# Realtime MS SQL Database transfer

Tags: sql-server-2005, maintenance

I have MS SQL 2005 Standard that is used actively (new data is added every minute). 
I need to transfer it to another server (new hosting provider), without losing the data and without downtime.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could do with re-tagging this question. 'mssql-maintenance' isn't a well established tag; there are several other more appropriate tags (sqlserver, for example) and you might want to add on 'replication' for future reference as well - I'm afraid I don't have sufficient rep on here yet)

Comment: Is this a one-off requirement or an ongoing one, you don't say? if the former then just a backup and restore will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) seems like the most obvious answer; specifically [Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx).

Comment: Not really, requires a significant amount of possibly database changes.

Comment: Is that one time? In this case I would go with mirroring. Contrary to Replication that works without changing the db structure. Once the mirror is complete, switch over sql servers and be done with it ;) Log file shipping is another method.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at database mirroring to replicate the data...there's a white paper [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917680.aspx).